# Gradle sync error in Android Studio giving error on root project

Tags: android, gradle

I keep getting this error when I try to run my app in Android Studio

> Error:(20, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_cmskf0wjjh0skzgqp1j9qzll2$_run_closure2@29a3fe65] on root project 'pomppyapp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   Open File

This is my build.gradle (Project: pomppyapp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files 2.3.3
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
dependencies {
}
```

Also another file there called build.gradle (Module: app) with the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pomppyapp.com"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 12
    versionName '1.6'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}

productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be grateful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this section in your top gradle build file is wrong:

`android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}`

It should stay only in project gradle.build file (in this case for module :app)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove these following lines from project level `build.gradle` because there is no android gradle plugin applied in it.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
dependencies {
}
```

It should be only in the module level gradle files in which android gradle plugin has been applied. `:app` in this case, in which android application gradle plugin has been applied (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer so that others can also find it useful.